# Needs assistance with Async or Multithreading task

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I'm new in parallel programming currently needs to run app as a background process which contains several tasks inside. Currently executing only do_something(), it blocks execution of do_something2(). Could please anyone explain me how to implement that? Should I use asyncio or something else? Thank you.

```
import sched
import time
import os
import subprocess
import asyncio

event_schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)


def do_something():
    print("Hello, World!")
    ...do my own stuff
    event_schedule.enter(5, 1, do_something)


def do_something2():
    print("Hello, World2!")
  ...do my own stuff here
    event_schedule.enter(5, 1, do_something2)


event_schedule.enter(5, 1, do_something)
event_schedule.run()
event_schedule.enter(5, 1, do_something2)
event_schedule.run()
```

Comment: Does your code spend a lot of time on I/O? If not, use multiprocessing. If it does, do you have asyncio-aware code and libraries? If so, use asyncio. If not, using threading.

Comment: No time on i\o, will use multiprocessing ,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, however, you need to organize your code as follows so that each process has its own scheduler (I have also modified/rearranged the code so that each process ultimately terminates after some number of iterations for my testing purposes):

```
import sched
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def do_something1():
    print("Hello, World1!")

def scheduler1():
    event_schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    for _ in range(3):
        event_schedule.enter(5, 1, do_something1)
        event_schedule.run()

def do_something2():
    print("Hello, World2!")

def scheduler2():
    event_schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    for _ in range(6):
        event_schedule.enter(5, 1, do_something2)
        event_schedule.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=scheduler1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=scheduler2)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```